# Kubernetes starting process take so long times

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I ran kubernetes several times with these steps but every time I tried to enable it i got stuck in the starting process.

i removed:

entire `C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop`.

`C:\Users\USER\.kube`.

`C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Docker\pki`.

none of them worked. i unistalled docker several times and again did't work all of those above solutions.

i opend the hosts file in the `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` path and it contains these information:

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
    127.0.0.1   kubernetes.docker.internal
0.0.0.0 activation.easeus.com 
0.0.0.0 track.easeus.com 
0.0.0.0 easeus.com 
0.0.0.0 update.easeus.com 

127.0.0.11 jimble.dev
# Added by Docker Desktop
192.168.43.121 host.docker.internal
192.168.43.121 gateway.docker.internal
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section
```

docker logs.txt in the `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Docker` path:

```
Version: 3.3.3 (64133)
Sha1: 68eba96de8051dcb12cf43b3a6955f1ee7156b4b
Started on: 2021/11/05 11:58:27.489
Resources: C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources
OS: Windows 10 Enterprise
Edition: Enterprise
Id: 2009
Build: 19043
BuildLabName: 19041.1.amd64fre.vb_release.191206-1406
File: C:\Users\M-Nowresideh\AppData\Local\Docker\log.txt
CommandLine: "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Docker Desktop.exe" 
[12:00:36.940][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:00:37.291][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:00:37.293][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:00:37.296][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:00:37.298][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:00:37.300][VpnKit            ][Info   ] vpnkit.exe: Connected Ethernet interface f6:16:36:bc:f9:c6
[12:00:37.300][VpnKit            ][Info   ] vpnkit.exe: UDP interface connected on 173.194.69.82
[12:00:37.850][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /features 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[12:00:37.852][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [796a41e6] <Server start> GET http://localhost/settings
[12:00:37.858][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [796a41e6] <Server end> GET http://localhost/settings -> 200 OK (took 5ms)
[12:00:38.005][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [674cf377] <Server start> GET http://localhost/system/disk-usage?path=C:%5CProgramData%5CDockerDesktop%5Cvm-data
[12:00:38.006][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [674cf377] <Server end> GET http://localhost/system/disk-usage?path=C:%5CProgramData%5CDockerDesktop%5Cvm-data -> 200 OK (took 0ms)
[12:00:38.969][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:00:40.183][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:00:42.298][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:00:42.492][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:00:42.495][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:00:42.498][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:00:42.501][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:00:44.251][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:00:45.322][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:00:46.962][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:00:47.396][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:00:47.399][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:00:47.402][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:00:47.406][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:00:48.494][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:00:49.724][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:00:52.742][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:00:52.885][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:00:52.887][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:00:52.889][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:00:52.892][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:00:52.893][VpnKit            ][Info   ] vpnkit.exe: Connected Ethernet interface f6:16:36:bc:f9:c6
[12:00:52.893][VpnKit            ][Info   ] vpnkit.exe: UDP interface connected on 173.194.79.82
[12:00:54.393][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:00:55.777][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:00:58.213][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:00:58.325][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:00:58.327][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:00:58.330][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:00:58.332][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:00:59.697][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:01:01.974][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:01:04.300][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:01:04.503][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:01:04.506][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:01:04.509][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:01:04.513][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:01:06.587][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:01:07.846][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:01:09.696][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:01:09.949][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:01:09.952][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:01:09.955][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:01:09.958][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:01:11.267][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:01:12.653][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:01:14.413][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:01:14.537][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:01:14.539][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:01:14.541][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:01:14.544][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:01:17.278][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:01:19.831][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:01:21.517][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:01:21.592][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:01:21.595][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:01:21.597][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
[12:01:21.601][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
```

i quite docker desktop and tried open one more time and sounds the results of the logs.txt are different.
heres another results:

```
Version: 3.3.3 (64133)
Sha1: 68eba96de8051dcb12cf43b3a6955f1ee7156b4b
Started on: 2021/11/05 13:03:49.968
Resources: C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources
OS: Windows 10 Enterprise
Edition: Enterprise
Id: 2009
Build: 19043
BuildLabName: 19041.1.amd64fre.vb_release.191206-1406
File: C:\Users\M-Nowresideh\AppData\Local\Docker\log.txt
CommandLine: "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Docker Desktop.exe" 
[13:05:00.621][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [12b5c2c7] <NotificationsClient end> POST http://localhost/kubernetes/state -> 200 OK (took 9ms)
[13:05:00.919][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="Cluster config received"
[13:05:00.959][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /forwards/list 200 \"Go-http-client/1.1\" \"\""
[13:05:00.970][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="adding tcp forward from 127.0.0.1:6443 to 127.0.0.1:6443"
[13:05:00.972][LinuxWSL2Engine   ][Info   ] msg="adding tcp forward from 127.0.0.1:6443 to 127.0.0.1:6443"
[13:05:00.972][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: PUT /forwards/expose/port 200 \"Go-http-client/1.1\" \"\""
[13:05:01.768][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [917503e1] <Server start> GET http://unix/kubernetes/settings
[13:05:01.773][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [917503e1] <Server end> GET http://unix/kubernetes/settings -> 200 OK (took 4ms)
[13:05:01.778][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] msg="proxy >> GET /containers/760f5a789c3bb78e920800142d47426d5cdfc893c17924d80c8c1d564a2e20b5/json\n"
[13:05:01.782][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /forwards/list 200 \"Go-http-client/1.1\" \"\""
[13:05:01.783][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] msg="proxy << GET /containers/760f5a789c3bb78e920800142d47426d5cdfc893c17924d80c8c1d564a2e20b5/json (4.8436ms)\n"
[13:05:01.813][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] msg="proxy >> GET /system/df\n"
[13:05:01.816][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] msg="proxy << GET /system/df (3.0627ms)\n"
[13:05:02.304][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] msg="proxy >> GET /system/df\n"
[13:05:02.307][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] msg="proxy << GET /system/df (2.6924ms)\n"
[13:05:02.922][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] msg="proxy >> GET /containers/a0c745105468871ca5cba6f12dcfe60c082df1e4e90d7200e514d7da0f623a68/json\n"
[13:05:02.928][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /forwards/list 200 \"Go-http-client/1.1\" \"\""
[13:05:02.928][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] msg="proxy << GET /containers/a0c745105468871ca5cba6f12dcfe60c082df1e4e90d7200e514d7da0f623a68/json (5.7053ms)\n"
[13:05:02.944][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] msg="proxy >> GET /system/df\n"
[13:05:02.947][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] msg="proxy << GET /system/df (2.8318ms)\n"
[13:05:03.350][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] msg="proxy >> GET /system/df\n"
[13:05:03.352][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] msg="proxy << GET /system/df (3.094ms)\n"
[13:05:10.978][VpnKit            ][Info   ] vpnkit.exe: Connected Ethernet interface f6:16:36:bc:f9:c6
[13:05:10.978][VpnKit            ][Info   ] vpnkit.exe: UDP interface connected on 108.177.127.82
[13:05:11.535][VpnKit            ][Error  ] vpnkit.exe: Socket.TCPv4.write tcp:108.177.127.82:443: caught Bad file descriptor returning Eof
[13:05:48.858][VpnKit            ][Error  ] vpnkit.exe: Socket.TCPv4.write tcp:108.177.127.82:443: caught Bad file descriptor returning Eof
[13:05:49.906][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: POST /diagnostics/gather 202 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:05:54.906][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:05:59.918][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:06:02.578][VpnKit            ][Error  ] vpnkit.exe: Socket.TCPv4.write tcp:108.177.127.82:443: caught Bad file descriptor returning Eof
[13:06:04.916][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:06:09.908][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:06:14.907][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:06:15.441][VpnKit            ][Info   ] vpnkit.exe: Connected Ethernet interface f6:16:36:bc:f9:c6
[13:06:15.441][VpnKit            ][Info   ] vpnkit.exe: UDP interface connected on 169.254.169.254
[13:06:19.911][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:06:24.911][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:06:29.915][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:06:34.906][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:06:39.908][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:06:44.971][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:06:49.912][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:06:54.921][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:06:59.915][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:07:04.907][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:07:09.915][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:07:14.907][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:07:19.907][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:07:24.913][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:07:29.907][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:07:34.920][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:07:39.906][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:07:44.322][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /ping 200 \"DockerDesktopGo\" \"\""
[13:07:44.334][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/goroutines 200 \"Go-http-client/1.1\" \"\""
[13:07:44.413][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /events 200 \"DockerDesktopGo\" \"\""
[13:07:44.466][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /forwards/list 200 \"Go-http-client/1.1\" \"\""
[13:07:44.919][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:07:49.908][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:07:51.584][VpnKit            ][Error  ] vpnkit.exe: Socket.TCPv4.write tcp:108.177.127.82:443: caught Bad file descriptor returning Eof
[13:07:54.920][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:07:59.918][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:08:04.915][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:08:09.906][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:08:14.908][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:08:19.918][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:08:24.911][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:08:29.909][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:08:34.908][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:08:39.906][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:08:45.107][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:08:49.908][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:08:54.904][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:08:59.910][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:09:04.919][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:09:05.050][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] msg="proxy >> GET /v1.24/version\n"
[13:09:05.065][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] msg="proxy << GET /v1.24/version (15.3549ms)\n"
[13:09:05.066][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] msg="proxy >> GET /v1.24/info\n"
[13:09:05.082][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] msg="proxy << GET /v1.24/info (16.2246ms)\n"
[13:09:05.083][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] msg="proxy >> GET /v1.24/containers/json?all=1\n"
[13:09:05.086][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /forwards/list 200 \"Go-http-client/1.1\" \"\""
[13:09:05.087][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] msg="proxy << GET /v1.24/containers/json?all=1 (3.3ms)\n"
[13:09:05.087][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] msg="proxy >> GET /v1.24/nodes\n"
[13:09:05.089][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] msg="proxy << GET /v1.24/nodes (1.6491ms)\n"
[13:09:05.090][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] msg="proxy >> GET /v1.24/services\n"
[13:09:05.092][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] msg="proxy << GET /v1.24/services (2.2178ms)\n"
[13:09:05.103][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] msg="proxy >> GET /v1.24/networks\n"
[13:09:05.105][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] msg="proxy << GET /v1.24/networks (2.2067ms)\n"
[13:09:09.905][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:09:14.905][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:09:19.906][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:09:24.912][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:09:29.906][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:09:34.917][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:09:39.909][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:09:44.910][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:09:45.966][VpnKit            ][Info   ] vpnkit.exe: Connected Ethernet interface f6:16:36:bc:f9:c6
[13:09:45.966][VpnKit            ][Info   ] vpnkit.exe: UDP interface connected on 8.8.8.8
[13:09:46.253][VpnKit            ][Info   ] vpnkit.exe: Connected Ethernet interface f6:16:36:bc:f9:c6
[13:09:46.253][VpnKit            ][Info   ] vpnkit.exe: UDP interface connected on 99.84.156.91
[13:09:47.129][VpnKit            ][Info   ] vpnkit.exe: Connected Ethernet interface f6:16:36:bc:f9:c6
[13:09:47.129][VpnKit            ][Info   ] vpnkit.exe: UDP interface connected on 216.58.206.100
[13:09:49.915][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:09:54.920][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:09:58.607][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: POST /diagnostics/upload 202 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:10:03.630][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:10:08.630][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:10:13.630][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:10:18.637][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:10:23.635][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:10:28.634][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:10:33.628][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:10:38.637][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:10:43.631][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:10:48.632][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:10:50.633][VpnKit            ][Error  ] vpnkit.exe: Socket.TCPv4.write tcp:108.177.127.82:443: caught Bad file descriptor returning Eof
[13:10:53.628][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:10:58.633][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /diagnostics/status 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:11:03.627][VpnKit            ][Error  ] vpnkit.exe: Socket.TCPv4.write tcp:108.177.127.82:443: caught Bad file descriptor returning Eof
[13:12:52.571][VpnKit            ][Error  ] vpnkit.exe: Socket.TCPv4.write tcp:108.177.127.82:443: caught Bad file descriptor returning Eof
[13:13:46.599][VpnKit            ][Error  ] vpnkit.exe: Socket.TCPv4.write tcp:108.177.127.82:443: caught Bad file descriptor returning Eof
[13:14:12.087][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: POST /diagnostics/cancel 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:14:12.122][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [c7837eaa] <Server start> POST http://localhost/usage
[13:14:12.122][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [c7837eaa] <Server end> POST http://localhost/usage -> 200 OK (took 0ms)
[13:14:18.852][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /features 200 \"axios/0.21.1\" \"\""
[13:14:18.858][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [a8b97655] <Server start> GET http://localhost/settings
[13:14:18.881][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [a8b97655] <Server end> GET http://localhost/settings -> 200 OK (took 23ms)
[13:14:18.931][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [ddf7ca34] <Server start> GET http://localhost/system/disk-usage?path=C:%5CProgramData%5CDockerDesktop%5Cvm-data
[13:14:18.932][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [ddf7ca34] <Server end> GET http://localhost/system/disk-usage?path=C:%5CProgramData%5CDockerDesktop%5Cvm-data -> 200 OK (took 0ms)
[13:14:43.597][VpnKit            ][Error  ] vpnkit.exe: Socket.TCPv4.write tcp:108.177.127.82:443: caught Bad file descriptor returning Eof
[13:15:09.610][VpnKit            ][Error  ] vpnkit.exe: Socket.TCPv4.write tcp:108.177.127.82:443: caught Bad file descriptor returning Eof
[13:15:17.784][VpnKit            ][Error  ] vpnkit.exe: Socket.TCPv4.write tcp:108.177.127.82:443: caught Bad file descriptor returning Eof
[13:15:26.574][VpnKit            ][Error  ] vpnkit.exe: Socket.TCPv4.write tcp:108.177.127.82:443: caught Bad file descriptor returning Eof
[13:17:21.568][VpnKit            ][Error  ] vpnkit.exe: Socket.TCPv4.write tcp:108.177.127.82:443: caught Bad file descriptor returning Eof
[13:19:10.678][VpnKit            ][Error  ] vpnkit.exe: Socket.TCPv4.write tcp:108.177.127.82:443: caught Bad file descriptor returning Eof
[13:22:14.690][VpnKit            ][Error  ] vpnkit.exe: Socket.TCPv4.write tcp:108.177.127.82:443: caught Bad file descriptor returning Eof
[13:22:44.643][VpnKit            ][Error  ] vpnkit.exe: Socket.TCPv4.write tcp:108.177.127.82:443: caught Bad file descriptor returning Eof
[13:23:50.589][VpnKit            ][Error  ] vpnkit.exe: Socket.TCPv4.write tcp:108.177.127.82:443: caught Bad file descriptor returning Eof
[13:26:52.608][VpnKit            ][Error  ] vpnkit.exe: Socket.TCPv4.write tcp:108.177.127.82:443: caught Bad file descriptor returning Eof
[13:27:32.564][VpnKit            ][Error  ] vpnkit.exe: Socket.TCPv4.write tcp:108.177.127.82:443: caught Bad file descriptor returning Eof
```

actualy i ran docker so many times and i got this error serveral times in the logs.txt file:

```
[12:01:21.601][GoBackendProcess ][Error ] msg="failed to lookup googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.: name exists but no relevant records"
```

Comment: Which Kubernetes solution did you use? How did you setup it? What exactly you mean by "got stuck in the starting process" - which starting process? Please add steps / instructions that you followed and more details to your question to [make it reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hello @mohammadnowresideh. Any updates?